# Openshift upload files in Android app

Tags: java, android, file-upload, openshift, symlink

I have a Java application running with Openshift and now I'm building an Android app which use web services to retrieve all datas that are on database, and it works fine.

The web app displays images with `<img src="/uploads/image.jpg"/>`.

The *Servlet* is mapped on `/upload` then read an input stream from OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.

Is there someone who knows how to do those kind of thing to display openshift uploaded files in Android's *ImageView* ?

I already tried `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());`
where `url`'s like:

- https://myapp-myacc.rhcloud.com/uploads/file.ext
- https://myapp-myacc.rhcloud.com/file.ext

Should I use a symblink to access these file publicly ? If so, how to create it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java servlets, but I imagine your web app isn't handling the urls for local static files. I would google about how to setup routes in your app, using whatever framework you are, to access static files on disk.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a java servlet that returns the binary data (or base64 encoded data) when you call it, then display that data inside of your image view on your android application.

Comment: Can you add some code or more details to do that please ?

Comment: Maybe something like this, but just return the raw data: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Comment: I already have a class like that in my webapp, that's the only way to get uploaded images from web, but I failed to use the inputstream as I said..